# Флеш-плеер встроенный в WPF приложение не отображается на некоторых компах Win10 х64

Tags: wpf, windows-10, flash, activex, x86-64

Странная история.
Делал лет 10 назад десктопное приложение.
А сейчас оно на **некоторых** машинах с Win10х64 не идет. Причем именно на некоторых. На остальных идет.
Стал копать глубже. Увидел, что не работает только отображение флеша. Сам флеш внутри крутиться, работает. Но при отображении - черный прямоугольник.
Создал совсем простое приложение с нуля: флеш и WPF. Работает! Показывает.
Упрощаю почти до такого же состояния свое - не показывает. Именно на этих компах.

Флеш встроен в WPF так:
AxShockwaveFlash в WindowsFormsHost в Canvas в Grid
Сам flash.ocx подключается через встроенный манифест (не регистрируется в ОС)

(дело сильно осложняет, что под рукой нет подобной глючной машины для теста. Приходится тестировать чем тим-вьювер, в редкие окна)

Comment: Кириллица в путях запуска приложения присутствует?

Comment: Сейчас нет. Но это не имеет значения. Сам ФП грузится и работает (подгружает swf, swf обменивается данными с WPF).

Comment: для удобства тестирования могу предложить на проблемных компьютерах снять образ системы через утилиту disk2vhd и развернуть полученный образ в системе Hyper-V (есть в win10).